# Using Core Data Transformations for Encryption

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I'm stuck on why my transformable classes aren't being called. The following screenshot shows my Entity attribute as a transformable:

[image]

According to the documentation, it should automatically call the class "StringEncryptionTransformer" and perform the transformation.

I followed [this guide](https://artlogic1991.wordpress.com/2012/07/30/securing-your-core-data-with-transformable-attributes/) in order to set up the class. I'm using the EncryptionTransformer and StringEncryptionTransformer classes provided, the only change I made was with the encryption to use RNcryptor.

Encryption:

```
return [RNEncryptor encryptData:data withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings password:[self key] error:&error];
```

and Decryption:

```
return [RNDecryptor decryptData:data withPassword:[self key] error:&error];
```

The saved entity appears never to go through the transformation, is there something I'm missing? I tried adding an initialize to the NSManagedObject, but the results were the same.

Comment: A good starting point would be to take the code from the link **exactly** and get that to work. Then introduce your changed such as `RNEncryptor`. Also verify that `transformedValue` and `reverseTransformedValue` are being called, put breakpoints in them.

Comment: I have tried that, the breakpoints are never hit. Core data never goes through the transformation. I'm unsure where to include these files

Answer (score 0):

you need to register value transformer like below

```
extension NSValueTransformerName {
    static let classNameTransformerName = NSValueTransformerName(rawValue: "ClassNameTransformer")
}

ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(ClassNameTransformer(), forName: .classNameTransformerName)
```